# acosf() returns NaN

Tags: objective-c, c, trigonometry

I have a iPhone application written in Objective C where I'm collecting the touch points the user draws on to the screen to create a path.

I want to be able to thin this data. One of the ways I'm aiming to do this by checking if the angle of a point is over a certain threshold. For instance, if I take any three adjacent points on the line called a,b,c, if the angle ABC is within 5 degrees of 180, then I could remove point b without affecting the line too much.

I'm trying to achieve this by splitting the triangle ABC into 2 right-angled triangles. I'm then using acosf() to find the angle at a (BAC) and the angle at c (BCA). I can then subtract both these angles from 180 to find the angle of ABC.

My issue is that acosf() is often returning NaN. When it returns a number I've checked it on a calculator and the value is correct. I've tried the values that return NaN and they don't work on a calculator either. I know that this is because they are out of range for acosf(). How Can I avoid this?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
float prevToNextDist = ccpDistance(prevPoint.location, nextPoint.location);
    //work out the next point angle
    float pointToNextDistance = ccpDistance(point.location, nextPoint.location);
    float nextPointAngle = acosf((prevToNextDist/2)/pointToNextDistance);
    nextPointAngle = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(nextPointAngle);

    //work out the previous point angle
    float prevToPointDistance = ccpDistance(prevPoint.location, point.location);
    float prevPointAngle = acosf((prevToNextDist/2)/prevToPointDistance);
    prevPointAngle = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(prevPointAngle);

    //work out the point angle
    float pointAngle = 180 - nextPointAngle - prevPointAngle;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've worked this out, so I'm posting my solution for anybody who might stumble across this tread and find it useful. Although, I'm using using my own solution, both chux and AProgrammers's advice is sound, and helped me come up with the solution, so I've upvoted them both.

As chux suggested, atan2() is the better function to use rather than acosf(). Here's the code that thin's the points data based on angle:

```
#define kAngleTolerance 3

    double prevPointAngle = atan2(point.location.y - prevPoint.location.y, point.location.x - prevPoint.location.x) * 180.0f / M_PI;
    prevPointAngle = fabs(prevPointAngle);

    double nextPointAngle = atan2(nextPoint.location.y - point.location.y, nextPoint.location.x - point.location.x) * 180.0f / M_PI;
    nextPointAngle = fabs(nextPointAngle);

    double pointAngle = 180 - fabs(nextPointAngle - prevPointAngle);

    if (pointAngle < 180 + kAngleTolerance && pointAngle > 180 - kAngleTolerance ) {
        point.remove = YES;
        [pointsToRemove addObject:point];
    }
```

Comment: Note: `fabs(nextPointAngle - prevPointAngle)` may range from 0 to 360.  Is  the rest of your code prepared for that range?

Comment: BTW, suggest your answer point out why you are using `atan2f()` rather than `atan2()`, which would go along with your other variables that are shown as `double`.

Comment: BTW: Consider a _very_ different approach to the original problem: for each point between 2 points, calculate the _distance_ of that center point to the segment formed by the 2 end points.  Do this for all such points and eliminate the ones that are close.  The math on this does not touch trig and is reasonable simple - but I'd have to look it up.

Comment: You are indeed correct that atan2() is the preferred function in this case as it returns a double, thanks for pointing it out, I've edited my answer. Your suggestion of checking the distance between the tested point and the centre point of the two adjacent points is a great idea. I have a feeling it would most likely end up being faster too, I'll be sure to give it a go. Thanks again for the input.

Comment: Minor point: it is not the distance between the point and _center_ point of the adjacent 2, but the point and the distance closest to the segment. [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line)  BTW: You can look for a minimal _square_ of the distance instead of distance.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Yes I see what you mean, as the point may be closer to one of the adjacent points than the other. Thanks for the link, I'll give it a read.

Answer (score 7):

A classic issue with `acos(x)` and `acosf(x)` is insuring the argument is in range.

Sometimes the calculated `x` is *just* outside the range -1 <= x <= 1 due to various FP issues.  Mathematically `x` may be in range, but rounding/precision sometimes comes up with values like `1.0000001`.  With that value `x` (to *8* decimal paces), then `acosf(x)` is NaN?

An alternative is to test if `x` is outside the arrange and bring it in.

```
if (x > 1.0) {
  x = 1.0;
}
else if (x < -1.0) {
  x = -1.0;
}
angle = acos(x);
```

---

Further: `acosf()` only provides a range of 180 degrees [0 to pi].  For your task, you may want to use `atan2f()`.  It provides a complete "circle" of answers.

Comment: can't remember everything from high school I guess!  I had to use acos(fabs(adjacent)/hypotenuse) in my case

Answer (score 1):

1/ float is not the default floating point type, it is double. float may be adequate for storing, even then you should do your computation with double.

2/ Without the code for cppDistance, it is difficult to be sure, but I don't think it computes the side of the triangle like you think it does (I don't think it is possible without having the 3 points as parameters).

3/ If your points are (xa, ya), (0, 0) and (xb, yb) and you are looking for the angle at (0, 0) (if it isn't the case, just change the coordinates so that it is), the angle you are looking for is

```
acos((xa*xb+ya*yb)/sqrt((xa*xa+ya*ya)*(xb*xb+yb*yb)))
```