# Output is -1.#QNAN0 and I don't know why

Tags: c, floating-point

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
  double stotal, smean, sd, ermean, total, mean, j, k;
  int n, i;

  printf("enter n numbers to be entered\n");
  scanf(" %d", &n);

  double x[n];

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("enter value for X\n");
    scanf(" %lf", &x[i]);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    j = x[i];
    stotal = stotal + (j * j);
    printf("%f\n", total);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    k = x[i];
    total = total + k;
    printf("%f\n", total);
  }

  mean = total / n;
  smean = stotal / n;
  sd = sqrt(smean - pow(mean, 2));
  ermean = sd / sqrt(n);
  printf("sum is                    %lf\n", total);
  printf("mean is                   %lf\n", mean);
  printf("sum squared is            %lf\n", stotal);
  printf("mean squared is           %lf\n", smean);
  printf("standard deviation is     %lf\n", sd);
  printf("error in mean is          %lf", ermean);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
sum is -1.#QNAN0
mean is -1.#QNAN0
```

The output for the sum & mean is off, I suspect its my total function at fault but I don't know how to fix it.

Edit:
The code was re-edited this time with initialization, sorry for giving out a confusing statement the code actually works for a very large value I just forgot to completely initialize the necessary variables.

Edited code:

```
double stotal=0,smean=0,sd=0,total=0,mean=0,j,k;
```

Comment: `total` is uninitialized, which you would have discovered if you turned on compiler warnings.

Comment: `stotal` is also uninitialized.

Comment: ah, forgot about that.

Comment: There is still a problem however, entering a very large value will still lead to the same problem. with sd & ermean output of ```-1#IND00```

Comment: @anno: Edit the question to provide a [mre], including the “very large value” that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`total, stotal` uninitialized.

---

"entering a very large value " --> For large `x[i]`, `stotal` may become infinite due to `stotal + (j * j)`.  Then a problem with subtracting infinities in `smean - pow(mean, 2)`.

---

> output is -1.#QNAN0 and i dont know why

Beware slight differences between real math and floating point math.

Consider `smean - pow(mean, 2)` may be slightly negative due to roundings of FP math, even if mathematically that is not expected.

```
sd = sqrt(smean - pow(mean, 2));  // What if smean < pow(mean, 2) ?
```

Of course `sqrt(some_negative)` can lead to trouble such as -1.#QNAN0.

Instead guard<sup>1</sup> against this:

```
// sd = sqrt(smean - pow(mean, 2));
double diff = smean - pow(mean, 2);
sd = diff < 0.0 ? 0.0 : sqrt(diff);
```

Advanced: Could use below to cope with -0.0.  -0.0 is usually OK with `sqrt(-0.0)` --> -0.0.  Still, nice to avoid -0.0 standard deviation.

```
sd = signbit(diff) ? 0.0 : sqrt(diff);
```

Similar problem [acosf() returns NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19437438/2410359).

---

Tip: rather than print with `"%lf"`, use `"%lg"` (or just `"%g"`) - especially when debugging FP code.  It is more informative with small values and less noise with large ones.

---

<sup>1</sup> With this code, any negative `diff` is certainly due to accumulated calculations and rounding effects and the standard deviation is indeed 0.0.  Here `diff < 0.0` is reasonable.

Be cautions about such generalizing this test though where the augment to `sqrt()` is far more negative than rationalized by rounding errors to avoid a `< 0.0` test hiding some larger flaw.

Comment: https://www.johndcook.com/blog/standard_deviation/ has a more numerically stable approach to this problem.  Algorithm changes a lot, but no negative square roots!